# Apigee and Hosted Node.JS

Tags: apigee

We are looking at using Apigee and are intrigued by the notion of hosting node.js code directly inside Apigee's framework.

From what we can tell, popular Node modules such as Express and others are included.  In a video, we thought we saw that users would be able to upload/incorporate other npm modules as well as needed.  But, we are unsure how to do that.

Any advice, guidance, insight, would be most appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your Node.js app along with other supporting NPM modules using the apigeetool utility. This utility packages all of your modules and deploys everything to Apigee Edge. For information, see the section "Use apigeetool to deploy your Node.js apps to Apigee Edge"

http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/deploying-standalone-nodejs-app

Also, take a look at the Node.js samples apps on GitHub, where you can find additional examples and instructions (in README files):

https://github.com/apigee/node-samples

Will

Comment: I suspected as much.  However, when we tried using apigeetool utility, we kept getting errors.  Now, as I think about it, it may be because our node app has no package.json file.  Would that make a difference?

Comment: Thanks for raising this question. It's possible the doc isn't clear, and we'll definitely fix that. But you'll need to install the dependent node modules along with your main node files with "npm install". That will create a node_modules folder. See if that works, and refer to this topic (where "npm update" is mentioned). http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/adding-nodejs-existing-api-proxy

Comment: I forgot to say that you do need a package.json file that lists the dependencies before you run "npm install".

Comment: If [this is you](https://community.apigee.com/users/157/wwitmanapigeecom.html) you should disclose your affiliation in your [user profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3009122/will-witman) and probably also in your answers. Additionally, please don't post link only answers in case of link rot; post the full answer here and the link as a citation.